# Website redirection to www doesn't work on SFTP using SSH2 (Secure Shell)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am having a serious problem regarding website redirection to www if it is not appended in URL. My website works fine if I use www.domain-name.com but without www the site does not work and displays the following error in firefox -

[image]

I am using .htaccess and it has following code to redirect non-www to www -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain-name.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I also tried following -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But no luck.

One thing i want to mention is that this site has been setup on SFTP using SSH2 (Secure Shell). Is it would be the reason? Because before installing this protocol, the site was redirecting to wwww but not now. Then how can I rectify this issue? Thanks.

Comment: SFTP or SSH has absolutely no relevance to the apache configuration

Comment: Your first rewrite rule is missing a `:` (and perhaps has the wrong protocol - should it be `http`?)

Comment: Sorry, that : was left in typing. It is already in .htaccess file. And i changed https to http in .htaccess but no luck still.

Comment: Your first rule is (now) almost identical to one I use.  The only differences are I have `[NC]` on the `RewriteCond`, a `$` (`^(.*)$`) on the regex, and `[R=301,L]`.  Can you try on another browser?  I suspect the 301 has been cached from an old (broken) rule, and that the rule is now OK.  FWIW, it's safer to test with a 302 (temporary) redirect until you have the rule correct

Comment: Might not make a difference, but can you confirm your file has Unix line endings?

Comment: It's working now fine. The redirect had been cached from old rule. Thanks.

Comment: Cool; glad you got it resolved.